# "See all inbox items" keeps loading

Tags: support, global-inbox

The 'see all inbox items' option is not working for me. It keeps loading and the page freezes at some point.

Is there any fix to that?

Comment: Anything logged in the console?

Comment: What browser and OS are you on (with versions)? Have you tried a different browser? Do you have any browser add-ons/plugins that you can disable and try again?

Comment: What happens when you [browse directly to it](http://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox)?

Comment: Nothing in the console.
----

I'm using Chrome. Version 55.0.2883.75 m. Got only 2 extensions, which I don't think are contributing to this issue.
----
When I click on 'see all inbox items', I get the login page [I'm already logged in]. 
https://stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=%2fusers%2f9755032%3ftab%3dinbox

Comment: Are you sure you are logged in to stackexchange.com? Can you link to your profile there?

Comment: If you go to stackexchange.com directly, are you logged in? If not, logging out here and logging back in should fix that. Having said that, that's not a normal response to trying to hit that route while logged out. Something sounds off here. Did this just start happening today?

Comment: Thanks. It's okay now. I can see my inbox. I opened another tab, logged in to stackexchange.com. ---------- I usually log in using https://stackoverflow.com/users/login-add?ssrc=head&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f. Should it be stackexchange.com instead? And why? 'cause all functionalities/communities/etc work fine when I log in using stackoverflow [except inbox, of course].